# Extend the timeout duration of a setTimeout timer

Tags: javascript

Hi Everyone I know it is basic and silly to ask but this question is eating me up .
If I have a below following code .

```
var timerVal = 900000
function myFunction() {
  setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, timerVal);
}
myFunction()
```

As per the above code an alert will come at 15 mins . But after ten minutes I thought to extend it for more 5 mins by changing the value of timerVal to 1200000. Now would the alert will come after another 10 mins . i.e. total 20 mins after the alert will come or it will come after 15 mins of the completion .
Suppose the code is like this :

```
var timerVal = 900000
function myFunction() {
  setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, timerVal);
}
function change(){
   setTimeout(function(){
     timerVal = 1200000;
   },60000);
}
myFunction();
change();
```

Can Anyone give let me know what will be the result and brief description why ?

Comment: in order to change a timer, you have to call `clearTimeout(handle)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result will be that the timer will be executed at the `900000` millisecond mark, although you have tried to change it to `1200000` millisecond by changing the value of the `timerVal` variable.

This is because in JavaScript it is *pass by value* and since you have passed `900000` initially, the timer is already queued at `900000` and hence cannot be altered by changing the value of the `timerVal` variable again.

So this code, is simply making the `timerVal` point to the new number `1200000` not really changing the timeout set earlier:

```
function change(){
   setTimeout(function(){
     timerVal = 1200000; //timerVal reference is pointing to a new number
   }, 60000);
}
```

To really change the timer behavior you need to clear the timeout using the id returned by the `setTimeout` call and create another one with the new timeout value.

```js
let timerVal = 9000;
function myFunction() {
  return setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, timerVal); //returning the id
}
function change(id, newVal){
  clearTimeout(id); //clearing the previous timer using the id
  setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, newVal);
}
let id = myFunction();
change(id, 5000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, in general to be able to "extend" a timer, you'll need to cancel it (using `clearTimeout`), and re-create it. For this you'll need to keep track of how long has elapsed since it originally started and calculate a new time.

The code below demonstrates a function `extendableTimeout` which you can use like the normal `setTimeout`, except it returns an object with an `extend` function you can use for your purpose.

The demo has 2 button, the first starts an action delayed for 5s. Clicking the extend button extends the timeout by another 5 seconds. You can compare clicking the extend or not to see the timings.

```js
function extendableTimeout(fn, time){
    var id = setTimeout(fn, time);
    var timeStart = new Date();
    return {
       timerId: id,
       extend: function(time){
           clearTimeout(id);
           var elapsed = new Date() - timeStart;
           var newTime = time - elapsed;
           setTimeout(fn,newTime);
       }
    }
}


var myTimer;
$('#start').on("click", function(){
  console.log("Started at " + new Date());
  myTimer = extendableTimeout(() => console.log("Finished at " + new Date()), 5000);
})

$("#extend").on("click", function(){
  myTimer.extend(10000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="start">Start</button>
<button id="extend"> + 5s </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIU, you cannot extend the time of a setTimeout. What you can do is stopping it from executing, and create another setTimeout with the new value. Like this:

```js
var timer = setTimeout(()=>console.log("first"), 2000);

clearTimeout(timer);

var timer = setTimeout(()=>console.log("second"), 2000);
```

You cannot extend it because the timer is created with the value the variable had at the time of creation event. It's not a reference that can be evaluated from time to time. It's a fixed value that is evaluated only on creation time.